# Is there any disadvantage to asking for money?

Tags: shadowrun-returns

For many of the side-missions during the game, you're given the option to ask something like *"What's in it for me?"*, at which point the character you're speaking to (usually?) will offer you money.

Is there any disadvantage to doing this?  Eg. does it affect the ending, or the Karma I receive, or can I lose some side-missions entirely?

Answer (score 1):

I haven't found any disadvantages but you often require something to be able to get more money. Such as high charisma, a lot of strength.